# Trouble with ESP8266 on Eero network

Tags: esp8266, network

I have an ESP8266 Node MCU and am learning to use its wifi capabilities. In my home I have a router provided by my ISP that runs a network we'll call 'network1'. I also have an Eero mesh network that runs in the house, called 'network2'.

When I upload the following minimal example and use network1,

1. my 8266 device connects to network1 (the messages in the serial monitor confirm this) and
2. I can use my phone and laptop to connect to the 8266 - i.e., I can put the IP into my browser and see a webpage telling me 'Hello World'.

However, I have trouble with network2, the Eero network.

1. I *can* connect my 8266 device to network2 (the messages in the serial monitor confirm this)
   but
2. I can't connect to the 8266 device with my phone/laptop. (Yes, I switch these over to network2 first.) I put the new IP into my browser and I am told the page is taking too long to respond.

I haven't done anything special with my network1 router; things just worked. With network2, I've tried various settings with my Eero - given the 8266 a static IP address, enabled port forwarding (on port 80) and established a firewall rule for it, but nothing works.

I can run many different programs through network1, and nothing works on the Eero network. Any suggestions on getting things to work?

My minimal working example:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "network1"; // or 'network2'
const char* password = "thepassword"; // real password used in code

WiFiServer server(80); //just pick any port number you like

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  //gateway = WiFi.gatewayIP();
  Serial.print("GATEWAY: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.gatewayIP());

  // print your subnet mask:
  //subnet = WiFi.subnetMask();
  Serial.print("NETMASK: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.subnetMask());
}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Prepare the response
  String s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
  s += "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
  s += "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>\r\n";
  s += "<head>\r\n";
  s+= "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\r\n";
  s+= "<title>ESP Web Server</title>\r\n";
  s+= "</head>\r\n";
  s += "Hello World";
  s += "</html>\n";

  client.flush();

  // Send the response to the client
  client.print(s);
  delay(1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but have you successfully connected any two devices on the Eero network? I wonder if you could add some Serial.println() to the loop() to verify that things are working as expected in network1 and then see where things break down for network2.

Comment: @garson Do you mean connecting two ESP8266s & have them talk to each other? I have done things like get my iPhone to screencast to my Roku; in that sense, I've had devices on the Eero network talk together just fine. But not any devices that I've programmed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Hmm. This suggests restarting the eero. https://support.eero.com/hc/en-us/articles/207613706-Help-I-m-having-trouble-with-my-eeros. Printing confirmations to the log when someone accesses the ESP (on network1, and then trying on network2) may point you in the right direction but I'm not sure.

Comment: no matter what, you want to use the server.on() methods instead of that painful low level packet handling in loop().

Comment: @dandavis Will that help with the Eero issue, or just make for better page building once I get to making real applications? At the moment, learning to write good code is secondary to getting _something_ working.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer though I'm not sure *why* it works. It comes down to adding `WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);` in the setup, as in

```
void setup() {
  
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  ...
  }
```

I was able to replicate success with another file on my ESP8266 device and Eero network as well.